# Showing html text in FlowDocumentReader

Tags: html, wpf, converters, flowdocument, flowdocumentreader

I have a FlowDocumentReader control in my application.

```
<FlowDocumentReader Document="{Binding FlowDocument}" Style="{DynamicResource FlowDocumentStyle}" />
```

And here's how I set the text to the FlowDocumentReader:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Inlines.Add("some <b>book</b>");
FlowDocument.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

The problem is that 'book' isn't shown like html, the tags are visible in the wpf application.

I tried using this converter:

```
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/XAML-to-HTML-Conversion-ed25a674/view/SourceCode
```

but then the text shown in my wpf application looks like this:

```
<FlowDocument xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph>some <Run FontWeight="bold">book</Run></Paragraph></FlowDocument>
```

and again it's not bold. How can I do this?

Comment: Use the [`RichTextBox` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) which is able to format individual words.

Answer (score 0):

Use UI Elements to show formatted text and them to InlineUIContainer of Paragraph.

```
 Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();


        paragraph.Inlines.Add("some");
        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        lb.Content = " Book";
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new InlineUIContainer(lb));
        this.Doc.Document = new FlowDocument();
        this.Doc.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

Comment: I can't do this, my string isn't just from 2 words. I made it simple for the example, but in reality it's large.

Comment: In that case, instead of label, You can try WebBrowser Control to display HTML formatted data.

Comment: I have to use FlowDocumentReader, just like stated in the title of the question.

Comment: You can use HtmlToXaml converter which is a part of Microsoft POC.                                    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129(v=vs.90).aspx   and then use the  below code to display html formatted data 
            var xaml = HtmlToXamlConverter.ConvertHtmlToXaml("Some <b>Books</b> are ready <br> <p>test</p>", true);
            var flowDocument = XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as FlowDocument;
            this.Doc.Document = flowDocument;